# How to retrieve lookup relation data through SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I have Detail table with the lookup relation table (Status). I'm able to take the records from the detail table, but i do not know how to take the value from status table.

Below i have given the query

***Lookup Table***  ::  **Status_c**

***It's Column*** :: **Status_name__c** & **Status_Code__c**

from the below selection how to take the **Status_name__c** & **Status_Code__c** column values from **Status_c** table.

```
QUERY

SELECT Width__c, Status__c 
FROM Detail__c detail 
WHERE detail.Status__r.Status_Code__c = 'B' 
AND detail.Packaging_Id__c = : Id
```

Kindly help me. In case any further information please let me know.

Comment: Now i have found the solution below i have given it.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the way below here i have the query.

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT Width__c, Status__r.Status_Code__c 
FROM Detail__c detail 
WHERE detail.Status__r.Status_Code__c = 'B' 
AND detail.Packaging_Id__c = : Id
```

Before, I used `Status__c.Status_Code__c`, and I got an exception.  Now, I have rectified it with `Status__r.Status_Code__c`.

Comment: mark your solution as "answered"  :)